# Duplicate WP theme + plugins + Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

I have to create a new WP theme for a client. They currently have one with soooo many plugins and it needs to stay live. Oh, and they're using Visual Composer for the content.

I duplicated this theme in a new one, and made some graphic design changes using WP theme test. But now I need to change the content too (so with Visual Composer) and they need to be invisible for the users...

Is there a way to duplicate the content/Visual composer?
Or does someone have another solution?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can duplicate the content by creating template in Visual composer.

Comment: Use duplicator plugin to duplicate/clone the page. It'll transform all the existing stuff. So, you can do edit in the test mode. Once all done you can publish it. You can also follow this link to see how to do so https://nerodev.com/how-to-duplicate-a-wordpress-page-post/

Comment: Well... Even if I duplicate a page, I cannot publish it because I don't want users to be able to see it. For exemple if I duplicate the homepage, one is published and the other is draft. So... How can I see the new homepage with WP theme test?

Comment: Ok I found a way :) Thanks !